# CSS not applying to ReactMde

Tags: html, css, reactjs, showdown

I'm building a notes app but I run into a problem, I installed react-mde, react-split, and showdown as dependencies using npm install  but the editor's CSS styling is missing, what could be the problem?

The source code: https://github.com/arturfriedrich/notes-app

[image]

Comment: You might have to import their styles (`import 'react-mde/lib/styles/css/react-mde-all.css';`) as they have mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde#styling)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 9):

This is from the Scrimba React course, right?. I was having the exact same problem. Here's how I solved it.
Just put this line of code in your App after all your imports:

```
import "react-mde/lib/styles/css/react-mde-all.css";
```

See also the [React MDE documenation](https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde#styling).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For sure is from Scrimba. I prefer run the projects in my local and had the same problem. It works for me, please mark the answer.